# Django Serialized Objects and Chartjs Interaction

Tags: javascript, django, serialization, chart.js

I want to serialize a Django model that represents some user statistics. I'm aware of how to serialize the desired Django model, but how do I get the ChartJS script to interact with the serialized model? All of the values for the charts are stored in the serialized object.

Comment: It depends.. do you want to use ajax for this or just generate charts on page load?

Comment: @mariodev I would like to use ajax for it

Comment: Can you give more details of how the model is serialized..